CUDA out of memory, when fine-tuning segformer mit-b0
I am trying to fine-tune mit-b0 segmentation model on satellite images to segment rice paddies on RTX 2070 with 8 GB VRAM but I get CUDA out of memory at the beginning of the first epoch. I believe I have some memory allocation problem, please let me know what is the issue. I think I should be able to fit the b0 on my GPU.
Main Code:
import os
import torch
import argparse
from tqdm import tqdm
import albumentations as A
from data import RiceDataset

from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from transformers import SegformerImageProcessor, SegformerForSemanticSegmentation

def train_step(model: nn.Module,
               dataloader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader,
               optimizer: torch.optim.Optimizer,
               device: torch.device):
    model.train()
    loss = 0.0
    for i, (images, masks) in enumerate(dataloader):
        images, masks = images.to(device), masks.to(device)
        print(images.shape)
        print(masks.shape)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        z = model(images, masks)
        loss += z.loss        
    loss = loss / len(dataloader)
    return loss

def eval_step(model: nn.Module,
               dataloader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader,
               device: torch.device):
    model.eval()
    loss = 0.0
    with torch.inference_mode():
        for i, (images, masks) in enumerate(dataloader):
            images, masks = images.to(device), masks.to(device)
            print(images.shape)
            print(masks.shape)
            z = model(images, masks)
            loss += z.loss        
    loss = loss / len(dataloader)
    return loss

def train_loop(dataset_loc: str = None,
               num_epochs: int = 1,
               batch_size: int = 4,
               num_workers: int = 10,
               model_path: str = None):

    train_images = os.path.join(dataset_loc, "images/train")
    train_masks = os.path.join(dataset_loc, "masks/train")
    list_of_train_images = os.listdir(train_images)

    val_images = os.path.join(dataset_loc, "images/val")
    val_masks = os.path.join(dataset_loc, "masks/val")
    list_of_val_images = os.listdir(val_images)

    train_transform = A.Compose([
        A.HorizontalFlip(p=0.3),
        A.VerticalFlip(p=0.3),
        A.RandomRotate90(p=0.3),
    ])
    model_checkpoint = "nvidia/mit-b0"

    processor = SegformerImageProcessor.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)

    train_dataset = RiceDataset(images=list_of_train_images,
                                image_folder=train_images,
                                mask_folder=train_masks,
                                transform=train_transform,
                                processor=processor)

    val_dataset = RiceDataset(images=list_of_val_images,
                              image_folder=val_images,
                              mask_folder=val_masks,
                              processor=processor)
    
    print(f'Train images: {len(train_dataset)}\nValidation images: {len(val_dataset)}')
    
    train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset,
                                  batch_size=batch_size,
                                  num_workers=num_workers,
                                  shuffle=True)
    val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset,
                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                num_workers=num_workers, 
                                shuffle=False)
    
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    id2label =  {0: "outer", 1: "rice_paddy"}
    label2id = {label: id for id, label in id2label.items()}
    num_labels = len(id2label)
    model = SegformerForSemanticSegmentation.from_pretrained(
        model_checkpoint,
        num_labels=num_labels,
        id2label=id2label,
        label2id=label2id,
        ignore_mismatched_sizes=True,
        reshape_last_stage=True
    )
    model.to(device)
    optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=0.00006)
    scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer, T_max=10)

    best_val_loss = float("inf")
    best_model_state_dict = None
    for epoch in tqdm(range(num_epochs)):
        train_loss = train_step(model=model, 
                                dataloader=train_dataloader,
                                optimizer=optimizer,
                                device=device)

        val_loss = eval_step(model=model, 
                            dataloader=val_dataloader,
                            device=device)    
        print(
            f"Epoch: {epoch+1} | "
            f"train_loss: {train_loss:.4f} | "
            f"val_loss: {val_loss:.4f} | "
        )

        scheduler.step()

        if val_loss < best_val_loss:
            best_val_loss = val_loss
            best_model_state_dict = model.state_dict()

    if best_model_state_dict is not None:
        if model_path.endswith(".pth") or model_path.endswith(".pt"):
            torch.save(best_model_state_dict, model_path)
        else:
            torch.save(best_model_state_dict, model_path + ".pth")
        print(f"Best validation loss: {best_val_loss:.4f}")

    print("DONE")

Dataset Code:
class RiceDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, images, image_folder, mask_folder, processor, transform=None):
        self.images = images
        self.image_folder = image_folder
        self.mask_folder = mask_folder
        self.processor = processor
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image_name = self.images[idx]
        image_path = os.path.join(self.image_folder, image_name)
        
        mask_name = os.path.splitext(image_name)[0] + '.png'
        mask_path = os.path.join(self.mask_folder, mask_name)
        
        image = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")
        mask = Image.open(mask_path).convert("L")

        image_np = np.array(image)
        mask_np = np.array(mask)
        
        if self.transform:
            augmented = self.transform(image=image_np, mask=mask_np)
            image_np = augmented['image']
            mask_np = augmented['mask']        
            encoded_inputs = self.processor(image_np, mask_np)
        
        return encoded_inputs["pixel_values"][0], encoded_inputs["labels"][0]

I tried to run the same code with batch size of 2 on Google Colab but having the same issue
Sample Dataset

Hi, could you please provide code for the class RiceDataset. And where can I download the data that you are using?

Hello! I updated the main code a little bit for 512,512 sized images and provided the RiceDataset code.
Unfortunately, I can't provide the full dataset, but I can give you a sample dataset, check the Google Drive link above. Thankss!
If you try to run the main code it will print out:
torch.Size([batch_size, 3, 512, 512])
torch.Size([batch_size, 512, 512])
and then torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory... error.

Please make sure you don't drag the grads too far. But simply you can
have a try with smaller batch_size. And below code line will help you see the detailed allocation of memory in GPU.
print(torch.cuda.memory_summary(device=None, abbreviated=False))

And if batch_size = 1 still doesn't work, consider further steps.

Clear memory after each epoch.

# ...
for epoch in tqdm(range(num_epochs)):
    # ...
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    gc.collect()


Reduce the image size. Currently you've set 512 * 512.
Reduce the num_workers while considering the balance between the data loading performance and memory consumption.
You can implement gradient accumulation if the batch_size is too small and it hurts the accuracy.

optimizer.zero_grad()  # Initialize gradients

for i, (images, masks) in enumerate(dataloader):
    images, masks = images.to(device), masks.to(device)
    z = model(images, masks)
    loss = z.loss / accumulation_steps
    loss.backward()

    if (i + 1) % accumulation_steps == 0:  # Perform optimizer step after 'accumulation_steps' mini-batches
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear gradients for the next accumulation

    train_loss += loss.item()


efficient handling of memory allocation is a very common issue with all neural network python libraries.
In your example you forgot to make optimizer steps during training when iterating through batches. Because of this gradients for each model parameter keeps accumulating. Correct way to implement 'train' function is the following:
def train_step(model: nn.Module,
               dataloader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader,
               optimizer: torch.optim.Optimizer,
               device: torch.device):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0.0
    for i, (images, masks) in enumerate(dataloader):
        images, masks = images.to(device), masks.to(device)
        print(images.shape)
        print(masks.shape)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        z = model(images, masks)
        loss = z.loss       
        loss.backward() # !!
        optimizer.step()  # !!
        train_loss += loss.item()  # !!        

    train_loss = train_loss / len(dataloader)
    return train_loss


always do loss.backward() when processing the batch
don't forget to do optimizer.step()
If you want to accumulate gradient across all batches instead of using variable loss save only the value stored in it train_loss += loss.item()

Other things to consider.

Force to clean gpu memory after running train_loop, especially if training finished with an error.

try:
  train_loop(dataset_loc = 'dataset', model_path = "model.pt")
finally:
  import gc
  torch.cuda.empty_cache()
  gc.collect()


Consider creating model outside of train_loop, pass the model inside train_loop and delete the model each time after running train_loop.

try:
  model = SegformerForSemanticSegmentation.from_pretrained(... )
  train_loop(dataset_loc = 'dataset', 
             model = model,
             model_path = "model.pt")
finally:
  del model
  import gc
  torch.cuda.empty_cache()
  gc.collect()

Last thing - you have a small error in the RiceDataset.
class RiceDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    ...

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        ...
        
        if self.transform:
            augmented = self.transform(image=image_np, mask=mask_np)
            image_np = augmented['image']
            mask_np = augmented['mask']        
        
        # !! encoding should be applied outside `if self.transform`
        encoded_inputs = self.processor(image_np, mask_np)
        return encoded_inputs["pixel_values"][0], encoded_inputs["labels"][0]

